# Как сделать commit в свой репозиторий после клонирования чужого?

Tags: git

Подскажите, как верно сделать: я клонирую удаленный репозиторий (шаблон сборки проекта), далее я работаю с ним, создавая новый проект, комичу изменения, но мне нужно комитить уже в свой репозиторий (своего проета), как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы клонировали с GitHub, BitBucket или другого подобного сервиса и теперь хотите получить свой *удаленный* репозиторий, то удобнее всего пойти таким путем.

1. Нужно зарегистрироваться на сервисе.
2. Создайте форк (fork) интересующего вас репозитория.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Теперь у вас есть собственная копия удаленного репозитория, связанная с изначальной. Клонируйте эту копию.

Теперь вы можете сохранять коммиты в *свой локальный* репозиторий, а потом пушить их в *свой удаленный*. Если вы захотите предложить свои изменения в изначальный репозиторий, для этого есть [специальный инструмент под названием пулл-реквест или мерж-реквест (pull request, merge-request)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505731/181472).

Подробнее об этом:

- [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/)
- [GitLab Flow](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/)

Answer (score 6):

коммиты с помощью команды `git commit` вы и делаете в **свой** локальный репозиторий, который находится в каталоге `.git`.

более того: программа *git* не умеет делать коммиты куда-либо помимо вашего локального репозитория.

---

да, произведённые в вашем локальном репозитории изменения вы можете впоследствии отправить в какой-нибудь другой репозиторий (в который у вас есть право записи). но это совсем другая история.