# Как использовать контроль версий в коллективе?

Tags: git, github, контроль-версий

Ранее я уже работал с GitHub, но делал комиты только я.

А как работать в коллективе?
Допустим, я выложил болванку Решения на GitHub и несколько людей его скачали.

1. Один сделал либу
2. Другой что-то еще

(Это 2 разных проекта внутри решения)

Оба программиста по очереди комитят не дожидаясь друг друга.

Что в итоге будет в гитхабе? Один комит перезапишет другой комит и в итоге только 1 проект будет в солюшене?

Как правильно работать?

Comment: Почитайте хоть что-то про гит и мержи. Ну как можно задавать вопрос, не поискав информации?

Comment: Погуглите - git pull и git push, а вообще тут хороший [учебник](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: Рекомендую почитать: [Зачем нужен pull request, если есть push?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505731/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-pull-request-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-push?lq=1)

Answer (score 6):

В простейшем случае, когда все коммитят и пушат в одну ветку, будет **push rejected** (пуш отклонён) у второго. Ему придётся сначала сделать `git pull` и совместить внесённые удалённо изменения, прежде чем отправить свои. По умолчанию Git не позволяет *перезаписывать* фрагменты дерева коммитов, только *дополнять* его.

Если они меняли разные проекты, то конфликты малореальны, и хватит просто `git pull` (чтобы удалённые изменения слились с локальными), а затем повторного `git push`.

*Есть ещё особо суровый приём для сохранения прямой истории, `git pull --rebase`, но прежде чем им пользоваться, стоит изучить, как он работает и чем может быть опасен.*

---

В нормальном случае, **лучше работать в отдельных ветках** (которые могут существовать даже в разных репозиториях, в случае форков).

Каждый достигает в своей ветке стабильного состояния и делает pull request (PR) (merge request или MR в некоторых местах) и согласно принятой в команде процедуре (скажем, если хотя бы двое кроме автора проголосовали **за**) принимают его.

Если изменения второго PR/MR основаны на устаревшем коде, и верхняя версия в главной ветке отличается от того, поверх чего сделаны новые изменения, веб-интерфейс сообщит, что **слияние порождает конфликты**, которые нужно:

- либо разрулить **при ручном слиянии локально**
- либо попросить автора кода сделать `rebase` на новую версию главной ветки, в результате чего конфликты будет решать автор новой ветки (поэтому это более популярное решение)

Одна из вариаций этого техпроцесса называется [Github Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/).

Answer (score 1):

Если коммиты друг другу не мешают, то они вполне могут применяться оба. Если нет - конфликт, все равно вручную его разрешать.

А вообще ворк-флоу должен быть такой:

1. Форкаете базовый проект оба (ну, или делаете каждый свою ветку от базовой)
2. Параллельно каждый работает над своей частью.
3. Загружает изменения на сервер.
4. С помощью пулл-реквест вливаете каждый свои изменения в основную ветку.
5. PROFIT!!!

Естественно, что солюшен существует один. Его как-то бить на части не нужно.