# Как правильно отправить релиз на git?

Tags: git, git-flow, release-management

Я использую гит для своего проекта, работаю один.

И вот готов у меня релиз первой версии, я следую совету этой [статье на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/106912/) и тут описано, что нужно создать ветку релиза и как она будет доведена до выпуска то слить ее в мастер и в девелоп, после чего удалить ее...

Но зачем мне создавать ветку релиза если у меня в ветке девелоп уже все готово... Я так понимаю, что мне нужно ее сливать в мастер сразу и помечать тегом и продолжать дальше вести проект в дефелопе.

Но у меня локально есть только ветка девелоп и удалено есть девелоп и мастер...

Вопрос вот в чем, будет ли правильно сделать коммит на локальной ветке девелоп , поставить на нее таг, слить в удаленный девелоп и уже удаленный девелоп смержить с удаленным мастером...

Я просто не уверен, что эта концепция правильная и второе я не уверен, что можно делать мерж на удаленых ветках...

Посоветуйте как правильно сделать?

Comment: Чего-то не хватает в ответах?

Comment: @NickVolynkin нет наоборот очень хороший ответ получился, не знаю как тут это работает, но решил привлечь внимание к вопросу, чтоб увеличить поисковую выдачу. Чтоб те кто будут интересоваться таким же вопросом могли без труда найти ответ.

Comment: спасибо. :) кстати, этот вопрос почти вышел на первое место среди всех ваших.

Comment: Если начинаете внедрять методологию Git Flow - рекомендую презентацию на русском языке: https://medium.com/ruopsdev/git-flow-presentation-b80643390888

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Сначала немного теории, чтобы обосновать практические рекомендации. Надеюсь, заскучать не успеете.

## Что вообще происходит и откуда взялись ветки develop и release

Указанная вами статья – про модель рабочего процесса под названием git flow. Это в целом хорошая модель. Она была придумана, чтобы упорядочить бардак и анархию при совместной работе над кодом в больших проектах, и именно в них она эффективна. Если у вас сто человек работает над одним приложением, если вы вынуждены поддерживать старые версии (исправлять баги и критические уязвимости), если в день делаются сотни коммитов — берите, не пожалеете.

А для команд, которые

- немногочисленны, примерно до 10 человек;
- работают по agile и дробят задачи настолько, чтобы они делались за день-два;
- используют в основном самую последнюю версию продукта и не должны тащить старые версии;

... git flow попросту не нужен. Он создаёт больше проблем, чем решает.

## Как сделать проще

> Но зачем мне создавать ветку релиза если у меня в ветке девелоп уже все готово

Правильно! Вам и девелоп-то не нужен.

Для небольших команд и соло-разработки больше подходят «легковесные» модели организации рабочего процесса. Самая популярная называется GitHub Flow, от неё отличаются некоторыми деталями и бóльшей глубиной проработки GitLab Flow и [Simple Git workflow (Atlassian)](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/simple-git-workflow-is-simple).

### Суть всех простых моделей рабочего процесса

1. Есть единственная стабильная (постоянная, долгоживущая) ветка `master`.
2. Любая фича или исправление бага делается в отдельной ветке, которая ветвится от `master`.
3. Как только фича или багфикс готов, прошёл ревью и тестирование, соответствующая ветка мержится в `master`. Потом ветка обязательно удаляется, чтобы не копить хлам.

Кроме очевидной простоты преимущество в том, что код не пишется «в стол» и не залёживается в релизных ветках, а выпускается как можно быстрее. Чем короче путь от идеи до продакшена — тем лучше для дела. Клиенты (пользователи) быстрее получают новые фичи, а вы быстрее получаете обратную связь от клиентов и деньги за эти фичи.

### Как создавать и называть ветки

Принято начинать название feature-ветки с номера задачи в трекере задач.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b 123-featurebranch
```

Вы же где-то ведёте список задач? Начните, если нет, и вот почему:

1. Чтобы не держать их в голове, т.к. это ненадёжно и съедает ресурсы мозга
2. Чтобы вы могли их оценивать, планировать, выбирать приоритеты
3. Чтобы хранить информацию о багах и способах их воспроизвести.
4. Тренировка для командной работы; вы наверняка не будете всю жизнь работать соло.
5. Если проект в опенсорсе, то кто-нибудь придёт и заведёт вам задачу-пожелание или задачу-багрепорт. Или возьмёт вашу задачу и сделает, просто так, даром. Нельзя сделать задачу, которая не описана, верно?

Формулируйте маленькие, атомарные задачи, чтобы работа в ветке шла 1-3 дня, не больше. Это важно для работы соло и критически важно для командной работы.

Локальные ветки желательно тоже пушить на удалённый сервер, это хороший способ не потерять код, когда пролил чай в ноутбук, `rm -rf /`, пожар, кража, метеорит...

```
git push -u origin 123-featurebranch:
```

### Как мержить ветки

Есть два основных способа:

1. Ветку можно замержить вручную, локально. В командной строке это так:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge --no-ff 123-featurebranch
   git push
   ```
2. Если вы используете GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket — можно [открыть пулл/мерж-реквест](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505731/181472) и потом его замержить. 
   При этом фактически мержатся удалёные ветки, потом вам нужно будет подтянуть себе результат мержа (`git pull`).
   Этот способ помогает проводить инспекцию кода в команде и разное автоматизированное тестирование, но если вы работаете один, мерж-реквесты почти не нужны.

#### Особенности:

- Мержить ветки нужно через `--no-ff`, чтобы всегда создавался мерж-коммит. Он поможет вам просматривать историю, он [помогает найти ветку, в которой был сделан коммит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/584278/181472), и точно обозначает место, где эту ветку замержили, его можно отменить с помощью `git revert`. Любите мерж-коммиты, они вам пригодятся.
- Не нужно мержить в `master` то, что не готово, не доделано и т.п. Ветка `master` священна, в ней всегда должен быть рабочий код.
- Никогда не нужно мержить ветку `master` в ветку фичи. Исключения — подтягивание кода из мажорного релиза в долгоживущую ветку, разные ветки для разных тестовых окружений и прочие ситуации, которые *почти не встречаются при соло-разработке небольшого проекта*.

### Релиз

Когда вы готовы сделать релиз, просто возьмите нужный мерж-коммит и повесьте на него тег. Используйте [аннотированные (annotated) теги](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Annotated-Tags). В них сохраняется дата и автор, как в коммите. Таким образом сохранится информация о том, кто именно и когда принял решение о выпуске релиза.

```
git tag -a v1.0 -m "Version 1.0"
```

Чтобы запушить теги на удалённый сервер, делайте так:

```
git push --follow-tags
```

Параметр `--follow-tags` нужен для того, чтобы запушить только аннотированные теги и не пушить легковесные (lightweight), если они у вас вдруг есть.

Не отмечайте релизными тегами коммиты в feature-ветках. Замержили, протестировали результат, отметили тегом полученный мерж-коммит. Всё, что не в `master`, не может быть релизом.

Для создания номеров версий используйте [семантическое версионирование](http://semver.org/).

### Выпускайте релизы как можно чаще

Поскольку ветка `master` всегда обязана содержать работающий код и вы всегда мержите в неё только готовые фичи, каждый мерж — это фактически маленький релиз. При этом обязательно каждый раз пересобирайте приложение. Не факт, что его нужно сразу выпускать для всех пользователей — слишком частые обновления приложения могут их раздражать.

Но постарайтесь собрать группу бета-тестеров (начните с себя), для которых вы будете выпускать приложение после каждого мержа ветки в `master`. Таким образом вы ускорите получение обратной связи, а чем быстрее цикл ОС, тем быстрее развивается ваше приложение и ваши навыки. В этом суть Agile.

### Практика

С учётом вышесказанного, предлагаю такой план действий.

1. Замержить (слить) develop в master.
2. Повесить на полученный мерж-коммит тег.
3. Удалить ветку develop и не вспоминать о ней до поры.

Comment: Хороший ответ. Если проект делается в одиночку, то я бы еще упростил. Держать постояной только ветку мастер. Работаете над фичей - сделали бранч (локально), все закончили, потестили - мержим в мастер, пушим на сервер. Релиз - делаем тег на мастере, пушим на удаленный сервер.

Comment: @hardsky я вроде бы именно это и имел в виду, и точно так и писал. Если в каком-то месте выглядит не так — ткните пальцем, я перепишу ))

Comment: А в целом за ответ спасибо! Я вроде так и сделал... Только я сначала создал ветку у себя локально от удаленного мастера `git checout -b master origin/master` потом на ветку девелоп сделал коммит и повесил таг и слил эту локальную девелоп в локальный мастер. Потом сделал пуш и тагу и ветке мастер. И в итоге удалил локальный мастер... Я уже немного привык когда у меня локально дев ветка и от нее я делаю ветки фичи а удалено мастер и дев... В удаленый мастер я сливаю локальный мастер для сохранения...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko точно создавали свою ветку `master` так? Может, при клонировании она сама создалась?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko сейчас какие-то уточняющие вопросы или затруднения ещё есть?

Comment: Меня смутил пулл-реквест и merge --no-ff ), для одного человека можно ограничиться локальными бранчами.

Comment: @hardsky про мерж-реквесты согласен, поменял порядок. Пускай останутся как ответ на вопрос "можно ли мержить удалённые ветки". А про `-no-ff` — есть много причин, почему мерж-коммиты нужны. Например, замержил fast-forward ветку из N коммитов, потом следом ещё дважды по N. Оказалось, что первый мерж надо отменить. Теперь нужно вспоминать, где границы ветки, а `git revert` создаст N реверт-коммитов. Бардак! Куда проще заревертить один мерж-коммит.

Comment: @hardsky про локальные и удалённые бранчи: 1) не будет лишним бэкапить код на remote 2) тренировка для командной работы

Comment: Я просто эту ветку когда то удалил и локально оставил себе только дев ветку... так как мастер у меня только для релизов я решил не держать ее локально и все делать в дев а когда релиз готов отправлять его на удаленный мастер... И вот сейчас пришел этот момент)) И родился вопрос... Но сейчас думаю пересмотреть насчет ветки мастер... так как вы тут все говорите что дев не нужен и только мастером лучше пользоваться

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko можно переименовать девелоп в мастер )

Comment: а скажите еще в чем разница отправки тагов на сервер вашим способом `git push --follow-tags` и моим `$ git push origin --tags`?

Comment: @Виталий, спасибо за правку ))

Comment: никто не подскажет, как интегрировать git в среду AIDE? Нигде не могу найти

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko насколько я помню, разница в том, что так отправляются только аннотированные теги.

Comment: @СергейГрушин это можно задать как отдельный вопрос, хороший вопрос будет. Кстати, через командную строку гит недоступен на андроиде?

Comment: врать не буду, не знаю... я вообще пока что разбираюсь с гитхабом. самое интересное что вся практика и разработка происходит в телефоне :) а недавно отметил свое совершеннолетие)))

Comment: А можете еще подсказать насчет семантического версионирования... У меня возник вопрос только к первой цифре которая ставиться как мажорная, написано так `МАЖОРНУЮ версию меняют, когда сделаны обратно несовместимые изменения API.` А как это возможно в случае с android? На моей практике такое было только когда меняли `camera API` на `camera2API` которая поддерживается начиная с `lollipop`. Но это настолько редко бывают подобные ситуации... Получается что первая цифра +/- никогда не собирается меняться? Или не так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko рассматривайте это просто как очень большие изменения. Например, с нуля переписали половину приложения, поменяли дизайн. Например, ОС Android в данный момент в шестой мажорной версии. Представьте, сколько человекочасов там вложено в среднем в каждую версию.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko дополнил про аннотированные теги и `--follow-tags`

Comment: -1 за абсолютно не аргументированную теорию по применению git-flow. Я его использую как в одиночку, так и в маленьких командах и никаких проблем он не создаёт.

Comment: @ixSci ура, конструктивная критика! Согласен, аргументов не хватает. Но у вас-то достаточно знаний и навыков для работы, а новичку сложно сразу осваивать не только гит, но ещё и git-flow. Ок, я подумаю, как написать лучше.

Comment: Новичку лучше вообще меньше использовать готовых скриптов, а делать тот же git flow самостоятельно, чтобы понимать самостоятельно. Плюс, чем раньше он познакомится с разными методологиями, тем проще ему будет дальше(в командах или самому). Т.е. с моей точки зрения, нет ничего плохого, если новичок сразу начнёт учиться тому, как работают большие проекты. И не очень большие тоже.

Comment: Не будет ли правильнее `мерджить` заменить на `объединить` или `слить`? И зачем двоеточние при `push`?

Comment: @alexolut я долгое время использовал в ответах перевод "слияние". Однако, такой перевод встречается нечасто, а в устной речи почти все говорят "мерж".

Comment: @alexolut а двоеточие здесь необязательно, но вообще это синтаксис `push что:куда`

Answer (score 26):

> будет ли правильно сделать коммит на локальной ветке девелоп,
>   поставить на нее таг...

Можно и так.

> Я просто не уверен, что эта концепция правильная

Она одновременно может быть правильной, и не подходящей конкретно вашему проекту.

> я не уверен, что можно делать мерж на удаленных ветках...

Нельзя. Вы синхронизируете локальные ветки с удаленными (fetch/pull), мержите, и синхронизируете удаленные с локальными (push). На самом деле даже ветка origin/master тоже является локальной.

> Посоветуйте как правильно сделать?

IT - такая интересная область, в которой множество правильных ответов.

В частности, для проекта с одним разработчиком можно обойтись одной веткой master и помечать релизы тэгами.

git flow и прочие методики работают хорошо, только если вы понимаете какие именно проблемы они решают. Пока ваш проект таких проблем не содержит, методики сами лишь усложняют жизнь.

Comment: Кстати, плюс за упоминание о том, что ветка origin/master тоже локальная. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Я бы не согласился, что она локальная. Ветка удалённая. Но мы работаем с ней локально: pull - скопировать удалённую ветку локально. Мержим или вносим изменения локально. push - копируем данные обратно сервер. На самом деле `origin/master` это информация о том, на какой коммит ветка `master` указывает указывает на удалённом сервере `origin`. Когда мы делаем `push` мы просто обновляем указатель `origin/master` данными из локального указателя `master`

Comment: @EugenKonkov, тут вопрос в том, на каком уровне абстракции мы рассматриваем этот вопрос. Высокоуровневый (основной) интерфейс git рассматривает их как удаленные, а низкоуровневый - как локальные.

Answer (score 17):

1 создать rc ветку
2 смержить с вашей dev
3 вылить rc ветку

Так  делается  для того, что в случае креша можно было спокойно переключиться на предыдущую стабильную ветку, пофиксить новую rc ветку и опять зарелизить. Удалять ветки крайне не рекомендую. На практике часто приходиться доставать изменения в других ветках. Но если у вас веток перевалило за N и вы в них уже путаетесь, тогда можно почистить и только локально (git branch -d <ветка>)

Comment: Есть несколько вопросов: 1) что значит "вылить ветку"? 2) даже уже замерженные нельзя удалять? 3) на сервере вообще никогда не удалять?

Comment: Что касается креша — это если мерж не удастся? Есть же `reflog`, всегда можно из него восстановиться.

Comment: 1) вылить означает сделать git pull на проде.
2) Да, представьте ситуацию вы разрабатывали модуль1 в ветке r1 сделали ~50 коммитов. А модуль2 в r2 тоже N коммитов. Смержили. Удалили r1 (полностью на сервере и локально git push origin :the_remote_branch). И вдруг ветка поломалась или модуль2 не нужен. Короче требуется восстановить только rc1. И начинается поиск коммита по хешу, а коммитов непонятно сколько. Но это не предел, представьте ситуацию когда вы помержились потом сделали доработку в rc1 потом в rc2 опять помержились. В этой ситуации ветку искать очень сложно.

Comment: Рефлог покажет последний коммит. Представьте вы вылили r3которая состоит из 2 веток. Это около 50 коммитов. Появился креш. Что легче сделать git checkout стабильная-ветка или искать хеш коммита и откатывать изменения

Comment: Так же креш может возникнуть не сразу, после патча, который последует и тогда вообще сложно будет сразу вычислить коммит. Поэтому крайне необходимо делать стабильныве ветки

Comment: Если мерж был с мерж-коммитом, то не составляет труда понять, какой ветке принадлежал тот или иной коммит. Кстати, в ситуации `И вдруг ветка поломалась или модуль2 не нужен. Короче требуется восстановить только rc1` вы что будете делать, мержить с нуля и переписывать `master` или делать `git revert`?

Comment: `Появился креш. Что легче сделать git checkout стабильная-ветка или искать хеш коммита и откатывать изменения` - правильно ли я понимаю, что вы храните все релизные ветки, чтобы в случае чего откатиться к предыдущей стабильной версии? А что если отмечать релизный коммит тегом? На него тоже можно `git checkout`

Comment: И ещё вопрос: `1 создать rc ветку 2 смержить с вашей dev`. А от какой ветки нужно создавать rc-ветку? От прошлой rc, от мастера? Вы не подумайте только, что это сарказм или я просто так докапываюсь. Мне действительно интересно, как у вас рабочий процесс устроен, тем более что вы, похоже, с сайтами работаете, а я совсем с другими категориями ПО.

Comment: да, работаю с сайтом, поэтому возможно процессы немного разные. В кратце расскажу как у нас построен процесс. 1 задача 1 ветка. Потом все ветки сливаются в одну rc_версия ветку. И эта ветка идёт на прод.

Comment: На проде git push запрещён. И все ветки хранятся в гите. Иногда производится чистка гита (приблизительно раз в 3 месяца), тоесть старые ветки удаляются из гита полностью (не локально а полностью), но релизные хранятся.

Comment: 1 если поломалась ветка то тут 2 варианта: знаем поломалась после чего - тогда git revert, не знаем - если веток которые сливаются мало - тогда git cherry-pick каждой ветки, если много тогда уже дебажить и смотреть анотации и мержить по новой.

Comment: А от какой ветки нужно создавать rc-ветку? Система такая у вас есть предыдущая rc_1, вы откалываетесь от rc_1 -> rc_2 и все новые ветки сливаются в rc_2. Скажу, что минус такого подхода 
возникает при мерже, когда таски остались с предыдущего спринта, а нужно мержить с новой веткой, что приводит к тому что разработчик забывает делать, в результате проблемы с мержем.
По поводу git tag это вариант хороший, но тут могут быть тоже проблемы. Откатились на проде, пофиксили, залили. Тут возникает человеческий фактор  мержа с коммитом  там где был креш (чем больше команда чем шансов больше)

Answer (score 17):

В том случае, что Вы описали Вы можете поступить 2 способами:

1. Пойти по пути git flow, создав release ветку и тут же её завершив.
2. Сделать слияние develop с master самостоятельно и [опционально] поставив tag на master.

Оба способа дадут одинаковый результат, но используя второй, нужно проделать меньше работы. Поэтому, на мой взгляд, стоит воспользоваться именно им.

Тогда вообще зачем нужны release ветки? Всё дело в том, что любая методология является набором некоторых принципов, которые были выработаны годами либо одним автором, либо группой авторов. git flow вырос из командной разработки, где, как правило, есть отдельные люди занимающиеся тестированием продукта, а могут ещё быть и те, кто продукт должен принять.

Вот здесь хорошо вписываются release ветки. К примеру, Ваша команда сделала определённые набор функционала, который требуется к выпуску, скажем, версии 1.0. Всё это находится в ветке develop и у Вас нет никакой уверенности, что код правильный(он не оттестирован как следует, и главный менеджер ещё тоже не изучал функционал). Вы могли бы выложить результат из develop, но что делать с простаивающими разработчиками, которые не могут вливать новый функционал в develop, т.к. есть чётко очерченный круг функционала выпуска?

Чтобы разработчики не простаивали — выпускаем release ветку, в которой уже нельзя добавлять никакого нового функционала, но должны быть исправлены любые найденные ошибки и неточности. Когда все найденные ошибки исправлены, и замечания учтены — release ветка закрывается, сливается с master и продукт выпускается.

Как Вы можете видеть, для Вас, как для одиночки, release ветка не нужна. Поэтому, просто обходите этот шаг стороной, если не хотите выполнять дополнительной работы и помните, что любая методология это набор *общих* принципов и правил, и почти всегда методологии нужно адаптировать к нуждам конкретного случая — если Вы не понимаете, как что-то использовать, то почти наверняка Вам это не нужно.

Comment: Последнее предложение можно выбивать на мраморной табличке. Полностью согласен.

Answer (score 17):

> Но зачем мне создавать ветку релиза если у меня в ветке девелоп уже все готово...

Вся прелесть веток не только в том, что вы получаете свою копию проекта, но и в том, что ваши коммиты будут логически объединены:

```
*   4873cb7 Merge branch 'allow_different_debuggers_for_each_instance' into develop
|\  
| * 75b5384 Reduce TTL for variable
| * 4d0552a Figure out context for debugger methods automatically from current debugger instance
| * 1e4b894 Allow &DB::state to return current debugger instance
| * 19de6dc Make debugger instances typed (objects)
| * b5a7cfe Call methods of current debugger instance through &DB::mcall
|/  
* ec61d37 Code comments
* ecbc39a Rename _all_frames -> orig_frames
* 7aa54f9 Do not hide DB:: from PAUSE indexer
```

Т.е. вы будете потом видеть, что эти 5 коммитов были сделаны в рамках реализации той фичи

**Не слушайте никого, что т.к. вы девелопер одиночка, то вам можно не следовать всем этим правилам gitflow**. Учитесь работать правильно изначально!

Используя модель `git-flow` и работая с чистым `git`, да, вы будете выполнять лишние команды, что будет замедлять вас. Но это не проблема этой модели, а ваша проблема, т.к. вы не используете нужные утилиты ;-) Например я использую [gitflow-avh](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh), отконфигурировал `.gitconf`

```
[alias]
        tree        = log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
        prb         = pull -v --rebase
        br          = branch

        fs         = flow feature start
        ff         = flow feature finish
        fc         = flow feature checkout
        hs         = flow hotfix start
        hf         = flow hotfix finish
```

и добавил алиасы в `.bashrc`

```
alias gn="git-number"
alias gb="gn -c git blame"
alias ge="gn -c $EDITOR"
alias ga="gn add"
alias gr="gn -c git reset"
alias gap="EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' gn add -p"
alias gd="gn -c git diff -b -w --ignore-blank-lines"
alias gds="gd --staged"
alias gc="gn -c git checkout"
alias gcf="git flow feature checkout"
alias gl="gn -c git log -w -b -p --ignore-blank-lines"
alias gls="git log --stat"
alias cm="EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' git commit"
alias grb="git stash save 'REBASE' && EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' git rebase -i"
alias grbc="EDITOR='$EDITOR -w' git rebase --continue"

gcd() {
    test -n "$1" && cd $(dirname $(git list $1))
}

source ~/.git-completion.bash
__git_complete gn  _git
__git_complete ga  _git_add
__git_complete gap _git_add
__git_complete gd  _git_diff
__git_complete gds _git_diff
__git_complete gc  _git_checkout
__git_complete gcf _git_checkout
__git_complete gl  _git_log
__git_complete gls _git_log
__git_complete cm  _git_commit

source ~/.git-flow-completion.bash
```

И работаю в консоли со всеми этими "не нужными" ветками быстрее, чем используя всякие графические тулзы, и бонусом получаю красивую историю, т.к. следую `git-flow`. Плюс под рукой остаются вся мощность `git` (обычно графические утилиты реализуют далеко не все фичи, а в основном только базовые).
Подробнее о том, как настроить окружение, можно посмотреть [тут](https://geekbrains.ru/events/218).

Не знаю как у вас, но в самом начале, когда я познакомился с `git`, у меня возникала путаница с пониманием того что есть ветки `master`, `production`, `develop`. Поэтому я для себя решил так. ИМХО:

- Ветка, которую катим на боевые сервера - `production`
- Ветка, в которой ведется разработка (то куда вы мержите ваши фичи) - `develop`

Да, и во многих статьях под веткой `master` подразумевают `production`

> Но у меня локально есть только ветка девелоп и удалено есть девелоп и мастер...

Отвечая на ваш вопрос как делать правильно я обращу ваше внимание на то, что Ваша работа **всегда** происходит локально, а с удалённым репозиторием вы делаете только синхронизацию. Поэтому

1. Вы делаете мерж вашего локального девелоп в локальный мастер
2. Вы делаете push вашего локального мастера в удалённый

Ну а далее я поддержу вот [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573773/179765) развернутый ответ, за исключением никоторых моментов:

> Есть единственная стабильная ветка master.

Её нельзя назвать стабильной, пока вы не проведёте тестирование. Во время тестирования вы можете обнаружить баг, для фикса которого вы сделаете дополнительный коммит в `master`. Соответственно на предыдушем коммите ваша ветка является *не стабильной*.

По этой причине придумали ветку `release`. В которой можно делать хоть сколько угодно итераций тестирования по завершению которых вы выпускаете свой релиз и делаете мерж ветки в `master`/`production` и `develop`.

Пусть что там не говорят, но в любом случаем вы должны иметь следующие ветки:

- `production` ветка - это ветка в которой гарантированно любой коммит готов к деплою.
- `develop` ветка - это ветка в которую вы сливаете ваши фичи
- `hotfix` ветка - эта ветка (чтобы не делать cherry-pick из прод в дев) в которой вы делаете фиксы
- `release` ветка - для спокойного создания релизов

Поэтому даже если вы программист одиночка я рекомендую вам следовать `git-flow` модели, чтобы *уметь работать правильно*

Comment: Спасибо, отличный ответ, хоть я и не согласен со многими пунктами. Про стабильную ветку я уточнил уже, что это стабильно-существующая, а не стабильно-не-имеющая-багов.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Тогда плюсуйте ;-)

Comment: Так я давно плюсанул )

Answer (score 12):

Проверьте, у вас должна быть локальная ветка **master**. И делать слияния надо, конечно, локально, а потом выгружать их в центральный репозиторий.

Что касается необходимости создавать ветку релиза, то здесь, наверное, всё зависит от того, как вы разрабатываете проект, и как организован процесс. В XXI веке, где есть Scrum, Continuous Integration и DevOps, разворачивание проекта может происходить по одной кнопке, и дорабатывать его напильником при каждом релизе в отдельной ветке не нужно.

Тут, скорее, вопросы к автору статьи на Хабре.

Другое дело, постоянная ветка `release`. Она может быть полезна для реализации того самого *разворачивания по одной кнопке*. Есть несколько разных способов реализации такого поведения, и один из них — повесить хук на **push** в ветку `release`, по которому новый код и будет развёрнут на сервере промышленной эксплуатации (он же *production*).

Тогда вы просто пишите и тестируете код в одной ветке, назовём её `dev`, и когда считаете, что код работает корректно, переливаете изменения в `release`, а ваш build-сервер собирает установочный пакет или разворачивает код на веб-сервере.

При этом теги, конечно, вы ставите, и ставите там, где вам удобно. Ветка `dev` вполне подойдёт.

Answer (score 1):

GitFlow - это проверенная классика и простая концепция. А потом если менять, то уж на GitLab Flow, где применяется усложнение в виде дополнительной стабилизации в pre-prod ветке.

Идея, что в develop ветке лежит самый актуальный код для разработки - очевидная и больше соответствует тем подходам в разработке, которые применяются до какого-либо флоу, что облегчает переход на неё с других CVS (Subversion, TFS), где логика поддержки релизов похожа.

Если начинаете внедрять методологию **Git Flow** - рекомендую **презентацию на русском языке**: https://medium.com/ruopsdev/git-flow-presentation-b80643390888

Там есть ссылки на плагины git-flow для IDE (Visual Studio Code, JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA, Atlassian SourceTree) и сравнение с GitHub Flow и GitLab Flow.