# Git не делает push на другую ветку на сервере

Tags: git, git-push

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.

...

$ git push origin Tim_Musharapov
error: src refspec Tim_Musharapov does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
```

Почему не удается сделать push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error: src refspec Tim_Musharapov does not match any

Это означает, что в репозитории origin просто нет ветки с именем `Tim_Musharapov`. Её нужно создать. Для создания веток применяется такой синтаксис:

```
 git push origin что:куда
```

Здесь `что` - это локальная ветка, которую вы хотите запушить, а `куда` - имя новой ветки на origin, в которую вы хотите запушить ветку `что`. А `origin` это название удалённого репозитория (remote), оно может быть другим, но по умолчанию используется такое.

Поэтому предложенный в соседнем ответе вариант `git push origin master:Tim_Musharapov` означает "Взять локальную ветку `master` и запушить во вновь создаваемую ветку `Tim_Musharapov`". Это работает, но появится несоответствие в названиях локальных и удалённых веток. А ещё ветка `master` у вас теперь занята под собственную работу и стало неудобно получать обновления ветки `master` репозитория `origin`:

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits

В вашей ветке `master` есть три ваших коммита, так что `git pull` в эту ветку уже не получится.

Есть общепринятая практика: называть локальные и удалённые ветки одинаково. Это не обязательно (т.е. Git позволяет делать и по-другому), но удобно и практично. Соответственно, если вам нельзя изменять удалённую ветку `master` то не вносите изменений по ходу работы в локальный `master`.

Поэтому предлагаю такое решение:

Для начала нам нужна ветка, в которую будем коммитить результаты своей работы. Она может называться, например, `Tim_Musharapov`, но [обычно ветку называют по решаемой задаче](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573773/181472), а не по имени разработчика.

Если такой ветки ещё нет, её нужно создать так, чтобы она дублировала `master` (смотрела на тот же коммит).

```
git checkout -b Tim_Musharapov master
```

Если ветка уже есть, обновим её до текущего master:

```
git checkout Tim_Musharapov
git merge --ff-only master
# если конфликт, значит там есть какие-то изменения, которых нет в master
# нужно смотреть и разбираться.
```

пушим её в origin, ключ `-u` сохраняет соответствие локальной и удалённой ветки

```
git push -u origin Tim_Musharapov:Tim_Musharapov

# в следующий раз из этой ветки можно будет пушить проще:
git push
```

А ветку master [вернём к состоянию как на remote](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431520/181472)

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master

# В локальную ветку master мы будем получать обновления с origin
git checkout master
git pull
```

Ещё немного про синтаксис `что:куда`:

```
git checkout somebranch
# Оба варианта создают одноимённую ветку на origin
git push origin -u somebranch
git push origin -u somebranch:

# Запушить "ничего" в ветку - значит удалить её
git push origin :otherbranch
```

Comment: Nick, скажите, а как можно было продублировать изменения с master на другую ветку (если она уже есть на локальном репозитории) - с этого все и началось, просто изменения начал делать в локальном master.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov Так я же написал уже.  `git branch name` или `git checkout -b name` создаёт новую ветку `name`, которая смотрит на тот же коммит, что и текущая.

Comment: А если она уже есть, просто изменения немного старые (все в пределах локального репозитория)?

Answer (score 1):

Потому что идет привязка к основной ветке. Делайте так:

```
git push origin master:Tim_Musharapov
```

Comment: Ох, вы правы! Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее об этом либо дайте ссылку, где можно почитать.

Comment: Если мой ответ помог - отметьте его, пожалуйста, как "Верный". Ссылка : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push