# Не могу сделать push в чужой репозиторий: "already up-to-date"

Tags: git, git-push

Меня добавили в репозиторий (дали права на коммит, пуш).

Сделал клон этого репозитория, создал ветку, закоммитил изменения.

Пытаюсь сделать `git push`, чтобы на удалённом появилась моя новая ветка со всеми изменениями.

Ввожу мэйл, пароль, в ответ приходит "already up-to-date". Данных на удаленном нет...

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а вы сделали `fork`?

Comment: "already up-to-date" Значит в репозитории уже есть такая ветка в состоянии как у вас. `git remote -v` правильный адрес репозитория указан?

Comment: @tCode если выдали права на пуш, то форк наверное не нужен.

Comment: @jekaby проверил, репозиторий тот. Ответ Everything up-to-date

Comment: @ks_on_v а ветка какая?

Comment: @ks_on_v `git push` с какими параметрами выполняете?

Comment: `Данных на удаленном нет` – а вы как это проверяли? Если на гитхабе просто посмотрели на файлы, то там ветка `master` всегда показывается.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> already up-to-date

Это означает что:

1. На том сервере, куда вы пушите, уже есть такая ветка
2. И эта ветка находится в таком же состоянии (т.е. точно на тот же коммит смотрит).

Варианты:

- Вы пушите не туда (а в какой-то другой репозиторий). Проверяется командой

  ```
  git remote -v
  ```
- Вы пушите не то что нужно (а например свою ветку `master`). Предположим, нужные коммиты у вас в ветке `mybranch`:

  ```
  git checkout mybranch
  # проверим, что коммиты на месте
  git log
  git push -u origin mybranch
  ```

  Можно обойтись без `checkout` и сразу выбрать, [что и куда пушить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/582909/181472):

  ```
  git push -u origin mybranch:mybranch
  ```
- Вы сделали коммиты не в ту ветку.

  > создал ветку, закоммитил изменения.

  Довольно частая ситуация: разработчик создал ветку, но не переключился на неё. Проверяется просто:

  ```
  # проверим, что коммиты на месте
  git log mybranch
  ```

  Если оказалось, что коммиты, например, в `master`, а должны быть в `mybranch`:

  ```
  git checkout mybranch
  git reset --hard master
  # теперь пробуем пушить
  git push -u origin mybranch

  # а теперь вернём свой master на тот же коммит, который на удалённом сервере
  git checkout master
  git reset --hard origin/master
  # заодно можно его обновить
  git pull
  ```

Comment: Можно же пушить сразу в другой бранч. Чекауты не нужны

Comment: @0andriy конечно можно, но поскольку вопрос задан новичком, я не стал приводить более сложный синтаксис.

Comment: Да, но пока проект маленький, никто может и не заметит разницы, однако на больших проектах и репозиториях checkout может занимать существенное время (не говоря уже о порче ресурса SSD).