# как найти бранч в котором был сделан коммит?

Tags: git, git-log

Например в этом дереве коммитов:

```
* ccfd449 Require to return undef if no digits found
*   93dd5ff Merge pull request #4 from KES777/clean_api
|\  
| * 39d82d1 Fix tests for debugging debugger internals
| * ed67179 Move &push_frame out of core
| * 2fd84b5 Do not lose info about call point
| * 3ab09a2 Improve debugger output: Show info about emitted events
| *   a435005 Merge branch 'redesign_interactions' into clean_api
| |\  
| | * a06cc29 Code comments
| | * d5d6266 Remove copy/paste code
| | * c0118fa Allow command to choose how continue interaction
| | * 19cb534 Emit &interact event
```

я хочу найти то, что коммит `c0118fa` был сделан в ветку `redesign_interactions`.

Какой коммандой это можно сделать?

Comment: Чем не устраивает пропустить вывод через `grep c0118fa` (или через `find c0118fa` для Windows) ?

Comment: в общем случае — никак. ветка (branch) в git — это **указатель** на коммит, а не цепочка коммитов (как, например, в svn или mercurial).

Comment: @PinkTux И что это даст? чтобы посмотреть инфу о коммите я могу `git show c0118fa`

Comment: В какой ветке был сделан коммит `a06cc29 Code comments` – в `redesign_interactions` или `KES777/clean_api`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin:  `a06cc29` был сделан в `redesign_interactions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во, я кажется нашел то, что мне нужно:

```
git log <SHA1>..HEAD --ancestry-path --merges
```

Для примера:

```
       c---e---g--- feature (уже удалена)
      /         \
-a---b---d---f---h---j--- master

git log e..master --ancestry-path --merges

commit h
Merge: g f
Author: Eugen Konkov <>
Date:   Sat Oct 1 00:54:18 2016 +0300

    Merge branch 'feature' into master
```

Из комментария мерж коммита `h` видно, что искомый коммит `e` был сделан в ветку `feature`, которая была слита в `master`

Comment: Сработает, только если был мерж-коммит. И это один из веских аргументов за то, чтобы делать `merge --no-ff`, а не `rebase`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Всегда делаю `merge --no-ff` даже если в ветке был один коммит, т.к. я не хочу терять данную информацию. Да и вообще противник прямой истории: от неё пользы ровно ноль. `rebase` Делаю только в двух случаях: 1. `pull -v --rebase`, чтобы получить новые изменения в ветке и избавиться от "фейковых" `слияний` (merge); 2. Когда обнаруживаю, что какое-то изменения нужно было добавить в n-commit'e (`git rebase <SHA1>^`). Естественно все эти действия делаю до публикации локальных изменений на удалённом сервере.

Comment: Со всем согласен. Плюс давно поставил )

Comment: @NickVolynkin: :-D