# Непонятное слияние в git затёрло работу

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

Сегодня на работе произошла странная ситуация, и хоть она разрешилась, её причины остались непонятными. С репозиторием работают два разработчика. Соответственно, в репозитории три постоянные ветки: `Alice`, `Bob` и `master`.

```
$ git branch --all
Bob
Alice
* Alice_n
master
remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
remotes/origin/Bob
remotes/origin/Carol
remotes/origin/Alice
remotes/origin/Alice_n
remotes/origin/master
remotes/origin/master_instance
```

Вчера перед уходом с работы я внесла коммит в `Alice` и подлила изменения из мастера.

```
git status
git add --all
git commit -m 'Изменения'
```

В результате получился коммит `0cf7f9e Add export all editable records for Admin role`.

После:

```
git push origin HEAD
git checkout master
git pull
```

На этом этапе возник конфликт в трёх файлах по 2-3 строчки. В одном файле работала только я, поэтому конфликт я разрешила. В двух других мы работали оба, а напарник был уже недоступен, поэтому я оставила свои изменения, а конфликтные закомментировала. Потом чтобы вернуться на свою ветку, я закоммитила в мастера изменения, оставив их на локальной ветке.

```
git add --all
git commit -m "Fix conflicts"
git checkout first
git merge master
```

Мерж-коммит, полученный в результате конфликта при `git pull`: `9d2fda5 Fix conflicts`.

```
$ git cat-file commit 9d2fda5
tree f10d0642a0bee9c08572afacc732e19aeef6f029
parent 62043f332ff8e6ca9e6d12058bddc490cb1694de
parent 0cf7f9e6e55ef80bf2fbfba69d8d2bee57955a75
author Alice <> 1480521034 +0300
committer Alice <> 1480521034 +0300
```

Потом по итогам работы пришлось сделать ещё один коммит в свою ветку, но с мастером я уже не мёрджилась, потому что там не было изменений.

Сегодня напарник написал, что добавил мои изменения в свою ветку `Bob` и у него пропала его вчерашняя работа. Ему пришлось откатить изменения и сделать новую ветку, в которую вручную внести изменения с наших веток, это заняло много времени и он нервничал. Ошибочное слияние, видимо, не сохранилось в коммитах, потому что он сразу откатил слияние обратно. `1314ced merge files from first` – это он вручную добавлял мои файлы в свою рабочую ветку, когда выяснил, что обычное слияние затирает его работу

На моей ветке его вчерашняя работа сохранилась. Он говорит, что виноват мой коммит, но не знает, почему у меня на ветке работает правильно. Чтобы не повторять косяк в дальнейшем, мне нужно разобраться, как мой коммит мог затереть работу у него, но сохранить у меня. Я читала документацию весь вечер, но так и не нашла, что сделала неправильно. Буду благодарна за разъяснения.

**Update**

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* 4b2be62 (origin/first_n, first_n) Fix different date types (array and
* 02d3a6f small fix
*   850cd31 Fix date at import_xls and print card
|\
* | 6510271 Fix date in cards and in import_xls
| | * e5243af (HEAD, origin/second, second) Правки в связаных формах
| | * 5da1775 правки в связаных полях
| |/
| * 3433552 set print
| * 1314ced merge files from first
|/
* 7df8366 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Правки в селекте, добавление
*   c7e2dd1 merge second
|\
| * a0a7832 правки в поиске связаных полей
* | 346d429 (origin/third) change font
* | 93fff9e fix styles
* |   6a11fc2 merge master, fix conflicts
|\ \
| |/
* | 390fc18 change work of map control, fix styles
* | 76bdbfb add gis-logo lib
* | 174a55d add logo
| | * 2cf67b5 (origin/first, first) changed
| | * 2cf07b3 Fix import shp bug creating new records with old info
| | *   9d2fda5 Fix conflicts
| | |\
| |/ /
| | * 0cf7f9e Add export all editable records for Admin role
| | * d8f7231 Fix integer to string strip decimal points
| | * 59e50c8 Add icon to Geometry spatial layers style
| | *   97d357a Fix conflicts
| | |\
| | * | ff3118c Fix geomcollection default geometry to point
| | * | 9648c8f Add GeometryCollection spatial database append, export, print
| | * |   f5f4469 Merge branch 'master' into first
| | |\ \
| | * | | a776df4 Merge master
| * | | | 62043f3 Работа со свзаными полями
| * | | | fb4b7b7 Правки - дома без точки
| * | | | 4d5fef4 Удаление пустых групп из списка слоев
| * | | | 7410f87 come back
| * | | | acca807 asd
| * | | | bec436a ghost
| * | | | 9d26601 clear debugger and merge third
| * | | |   502a766 clear conflict
| |\ \ \ \
|/ / / / /
| * | | | e86d785 Настройка слоев, правки в валидации модели, создание отдельног
* | | | | bdbe5d3 merge master
* | | | |   b5b8bc5 Merge branch 'master' into third
|\ \ \ \ \
| |/ / / /
| * | | | 67a042c Правки в окне авторизации
| * | | | 6ddfc73 Удаление кнопки фильтра из кластерных слоев
| * | | | 40ca02e Правки в загрузке кластерных слоев.
| | |_|/
| |/| |
| * | | 2ebfeb1 changed model on edit table
| * | | 47ee6c5 Запрет на редактирование геометрии таблицы.
| * | | e9f1e5d правки в создании правил отображения слоев
| * | | 40152bb Удаление сессий, изменние страницы авторизации
| * | | 7f82cad Правки в ддп
| * | | c63f80b clear debugger and import pdb;
| * | | 0bca931 Правки в проекте, удаление что здесь, правки экспорта сводной ст
| | |/
| |/|
* | | 193cfcc icon markercluster
* | | b82aa6e fix backbone-tree, models, form for point, polygon
* | | 50ea454 add displaystyle form for line, polygon, multipolygon
* | | 85188fb add changing of pictogram size in vectorlayers
* | | c6da90a rerurn pictogram 126482.svg
* | | 9804246 Правка отображения фото для слоев со статистикой, отдельная форма
```

**Update 2**

```
    $ git log --format="%h %ai %an %d %s" --all --graph
* 02d3a6f 2016-12-05 10:28:30 +0300 Alice  small fix
*   850cd31 2016-12-05 10:26:34 +0300 Alice  Fix date at import_xls and print
|\
* | 6510271 2016-12-02 18:15:48 +0300 Alice  Fix date in cards and in import_
| | * e5243af 2016-12-02 17:23:02 +0300 Bob  (origin/Bob, Bob) Правки в св
| | * 5da1775 2016-12-02 15:49:38 +0300 Bob  правки в связаных полях
| |/
| * 3433552 2016-12-02 11:36:14 +0300 Bob  set print
| * 1314ced 2016-12-02 11:23:09 +0300 Bob  merge files from Alice
|/
* 7df8366 2016-12-02 09:54:26 +0300 Bob  (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master,
*   c7e2dd1 2016-12-01 15:00:38 +0300 Bob  merge Bob
|\
| * a0a7832 2016-12-01 14:58:34 +0300 Bob  правки в поиске связаных полей
* | 346d429 2016-12-01 10:32:21 +0300 Carol  (origin/Carol
* | 93fff9e 2016-12-01 10:09:45 +0300 Carol  fix styles
* |   6a11fc2 2016-12-01 09:43:36 +0300 Carol  merge master
|\ \
| |/
* | 390fc18 2016-11-30 18:21:07 +0300 Carol  change work of
* | 76bdbfb 2016-11-30 12:41:24 +0300 Carol  add gis-logo l
* | 174a55d 2016-11-29 18:42:50 +0300 Carol  add logo
| | * 2cf67b5 2016-12-02 10:43:56 +0300 Alice  (origin/Alice, Alice) chan
```

Comment: `git pull ` внутри делает `git fetch; git merge origin/master`, так что конфликт при pull - это конфликт слияния. Причина вероятно в том, что разошлись ветки `master` (ваш) и `origin/master` (на удалённом репозитории). Нужно было делать `git pull --rebase`, например.

Comment: Можно поточнее описать что сделал напарник? В какой мастер он влил какие ваши изменения?

Comment: @a.chugunov  **В какой мастер он влил** - напарник вливал мои изменения не в мастера, а в свою ветку, пост обновлён. ** какие ваши изменения** - см. в посте `Потом по итогам работы пришлось сделать ещё один коммит в свою ветку, но с мастером я уже не мёрджилась, потому что там не было изменений.` - всё, что было в моей ветке. По сути он делал те же действия, что и я, только после слияния `second merge master` выполнил слияние `second merge first`.

Comment: Ага, спасибо, поразбираюсь. Кстати, насчёт модели «по одной постоянной ветке на разработчика» — думаю, что в ней есть ряд проблем и можно делать лучше. Рекомендую почитать ответы (все 6) тут: [Как правильно отправить релиз на git?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573743/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bd%d0%b0-git)

Comment: А `first_n` — это вы себе новую ветку завели взамен `first`, так?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Коммит `7df83664` - последний перед слиянием `second merge first`, которое вызвало ошибку. Остальные сделаны позже. Да, `first_n` - моя новая ветка. Здесь ещё может быть проблема в том, что какие-то изменения нужно сделать-прямо-сейчас-и-скинуть-файл, поэтому я отправляла некоторые изменения файлами на почту... но это не были те файлы, в которых появились конфликты или ошибки.

Comment: `1314ced merge files from first` – это слияние делал коллега и у него пропали изменения, так?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Добавила, имена в ветках для удобства тоже поменяла.  `Fri Dec 2 09:54:26` - коммит перед проблемой.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49588/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-mae).

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Что произошло

### 1.1 Конфликт при `git pull`

Команда `git pull` внутри себя выполняет две другие команды:

1. `git fetch`. С удалённого сервера забираются данные по всем указателям (ветки и коммиты).
2. `git merge`. В текущую ветку мержится та, которая указана как upstream branch. Для `master` это как правило `origin/master`.

Если `master` является предком `origin/master`, т.е просто отстаёт на сколько-то коммитов, то выполняется fast-forward merge: ветка `master` переставляется на тот же коммит, что и `origin/master`

Если в результате `git pull` появляются конфликты, значит две ветки разошлись. У них где-то есть общий предок, но в каждой есть не менее одного отличающегося коммита. Именно это и произошло.

```
$ git cat-file commit 9d2fda5
tree f10d0642a0bee9c08572afacc732e19aeef6f029
parent 62043f332ff8e6ca9e6d12058bddc490cb1694de
parent 0cf7f9e6e55ef80bf2fbfba69d8d2bee57955a75
```

Первым предком указан `62043f3 Работа со свзаными полями`. Этот коммит находился на текущей ветке, т.е. вашей ветке `master`.

Вторым предком указан `0cf7f9e Add export all editable records for Admin role`. Это коммит из той ветки, которую мержили в текущую. Неожиданно, но это ваш собственный только что сделанный коммит.

Как можно было добиться такого эффекта? Есть пара вариантов.

1. Запушить свою ветку в `origin/master`:

   ```
   git checkout Alice
   ...
   git commit ...
   git push origin master
   ```

   Тогда изменилось бы содержимое `origin/master`. Наш `git pull` в `master` сработал бы точно так, как наблюдалось. Но тогда у Carol тоже появился бы этот коммит, чего не произошло. Видим, что у коммита `6a11fc2 merge master, fix conflicts` в предках тот же `62043f3 Работа со свзаными полями`
2. Сделать `git pull` из другой ветки

   ```
   git commit 
   git push origin HEAD 
   git checkout master
   git pull origin Alice
   ```

   В результате в ваш `master` мержится только что запушенное содержимое `origin/Alice`. Похоже, что именно это и произошло.

### 1.2 Пропали изменения у коллеги после мержа

> допишу позже, когда коллега уточнит подробности пропажи

## 2. Что делать, чтобы избежать будущих ошибок

> Тоже допишу вечером, пока оставлю оглавление

1. Использовать `git pull --set-upstream`
2. От модели «по ветке на разработчика» перейти к модели «по ветке на фичу»
3. Мержить только feature-ветки в `master`, но не `master` в другие ветки и не другие ветки между собой.
4. Предотвращать попадание нерабочего кода в `master`:

   1. Оставить право на мерж в мастер только тимлиду
   2. Прогонять тесты на коммитах.