# Почему удалённые на сервере ветки остаются в локальном репозитории (origin/...)?

Tags: git, git-branch

Описание проблемы: в Visual Studio в Team Explorer создаю новую ветку, комичу в нее какие-то изменения и делаю Publish этой ветки на GitLab. Там создаю Pull Request после которого мержу созданую ветку в master, при этом после мержа ветку удаляю. Затем в Visual Studio делаю Pull и внесенные изменения появляются в ветке master. 
Если посмотреть на вкладку Branches в Team Explorer, то та ветка, которая была удалена на удаленном репозитории остается висеть в списке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я могу вызвать контекстное меню на ветке и удалить ее вручную. Но даже если так, то я не понимаю почему эти ветки у меня остаются в remotes/origin.

Вопрос: должны ли ветки удаляться локально автоматически после того как я удалил их на удаленном репозитории? Или это нормальное поведение и я их должен удалять сам?

Comment: А если сделать fetch этой ветки?

Comment: точно также получается. 
я недавно начал разбираться с гитом, сначале посмотрел как работать через консоль с ним, там у меня такой проблемы не было, но там у меня правда было несколько локальных репозиториев.

Comment: первое правило гита - не использовать гуевые утилиты. pull по умолчанию вытягивает только текущую ветку. Он не трогает удаленные. Если хочется, что бы подчищал удаленные ветки - используейте параметр `--prune`. Если хочется, что бы это было автоматом - выставьте в конфиге `git config remote.origin.prune true`

Comment: это ответ, спасибо! у меня еще вопрос небольшой родился, удобно ли работать с консолью в большом проекте? удобно ли все время мержить ветки вручную? я раньше в меркуриале работал и у нас были адские мержи даже с гуи, без гуи вообще не представляю как мержить. есть ли практика работать церез консоль, но для мержа юзать какой-то гуи для мержа, например из студии? звучит как костыль:)

Comment: @syler через gui бывает удобно мержить, т.к. всё наглядно. Если мержи прямо адские (много файлов, много конфликтов), то возможно вы просто делаете их слишком редко. Подумайте о том чтобы дробить задачи на фрагменты поменьше, соответственно вы будете мержить ветки фич обратно в стабильную ветку чаще и с меньшими изменениями.

Comment: Но в целом я согласен с @KoVadim — учитесь работать с консолью, она даёт больший контроль и точность. А ещё рекомендую поизучать, как гит устроен внутри. Когда у вас будет в голове ясная модель того, что вы делаете, и вы привыкнете думать в терминах [графов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84), вам будет гораздо легче, даже на больших проектах со сложной историей.

Comment: Раз уж KoVadim попиарил git-flow, позволю себе упомянуть альтернативный ему [github/gitlab-flow](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573773/181472).

Comment: @NickVolynkin я понял, спсибо большое за советы!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Первое правило гита - не использовать гуевые утилиты. Если быть точнее - не используте гуевые утилиты для действий, которые изменяют репозиторий. В случае любых несостыковок - сразу в консоль.

pull по умолчанию вытягивает только текущую ветку. [политика simple](https://habrahabr.ru/post/225251/). Он не трогает удаленные. Если хочется, что бы подчищал удаленные ветки - используейте параметр --prune:

```
git pull --prune
```

или

```
git fetch --prune
```

Если хочется, что бы это было автоматом - выставьте в конфиге `git config remote.origin.prune true`.

Если мержди большие и страшные, значит в команде кто то делает не то, что нужно. Дробите задачи на мелкие фичи,  регулярно подливайте мастер (develop) в Вашу ветку.

И в конце концов, посмотрите на [git flow](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/index.ru_RU.html)!

Comment: Двумя руками за мелкие фичи и git flow. )

Comment: спасибо за ответ еще раз!

Comment: Первое правило гита — если что-то можно сделать легко одним нажатием кнопки в GUI, пользуйтесь кнопкой. Не надо лезть без нужды в терминал при наличии нормального графического интерфейса.

Comment: И вы, наверное, попутали push и pull. При pull, по умолчанию, скачиваются все ветки. Push отправляет только одну текущую.

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на опцию **Prune remote branches during fetch**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]