# Как правильно при использовании git получить и потом смержить измениения?

Tags: git

Такая проблема я пользуюсь vim и каждый раз когда я делаю `git pull` то изменения автоматически стягиваются и мержатся

Мне нужно не так, я хочу получить изменения посмотреть какие файлы получены и что в них было изменено и потом сделать слияние

Так сказать вручную сделать процесс

А то так получается я делаю `git pull` и получаю сообщение о авто мердже, а что там было в авто мердже не понятно

Comment: `я пользуюсь vim` – а как это влияет?

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну это я просто, чтоб было ясно что я использую в данной ситуации

Comment: Ясно. Краткий ответ от меня: делайте все коммиты в фиче-ветки, никогда не в мастер. Тогда у вас не будет (почти никогда) проблем с мержем. Подробнее: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573773/181472.

Comment: Пока что-то нет времени написать подробный ответ тут. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно всегда делать git fetch, а потом ручками все сливать. Но как по мне - это закат солнца вручную. Есть более красивые пути. [ff-only](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---no-ff):

```
git pull --ff-only
```

В этом случае есть можно утянуть без мерджа - все пройдет хорошо, если нет - не будет мерджа и команда возвратит ненулевой код возврата. Удобно для скриптов. Настраивается и в конфиге - [pull.ff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pullff)

Вторая штука - [--no-commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull---no-commit)

```
git pull --no-commit
```

в этом случае, если возникнет необходимость мерджа, то сам мердж произойдет, но не будет коммититься. То есть, будет возможность решить все ручками и закоммитить.

Самое вкусное, но и самое "страшное для новичков" - [--rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#git-pull--r)

```
git pull --rebase
```

В этом случае, если есть изменения в удаленной ветки и в локальной произойдет ребейз, для любителей ровной истории самое оно. Если говорить по-простому, то произойдет следующее - Ваши последние изменения будут запомнены, удаленная ветка подтянута и изменения приложатся поверх. Ещё проще - это все будет выглядеть как будто только что притянули изменения (припулили) и сделали свои локальные  изменения. Естественно, если изменения конфликтуют, то git предложит все решить. Иногда и автоматом.

Comment: Мне кажется вот эта команда лучше `git pull --no-commit`. То есть я смогу взять мердж и посмотреть, что мне нужно а что нет и уже сделать коммит самому. Вроде как то, что нужно... Только не пойму как посмотреть файлы которые были смержены - ведь я хочу проверить что все в порядке и ничего лишнего не появилось а если появилось то убрать

Comment: git status обычно отвечает на 99% подобных вопросов.

Comment: Я если честно не до коца понял что все таки лучше `git pull --no-commit`  или `git pull --rebase`?

Comment: Они делают разные вещи. Мердж или ребейз - известный холивар.

Comment: ИМХО, главный недостаток pull'а в том, что у merge-коммита первым предком будет моя feature-ветка, а не master. В некоторых случаях это сильно мешает и остается только fetch + checkout + merge

Answer (score 2):

> я хочу получить изменения

Для этого делайте `git fetch`. Эта команда [стягивает](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8#Fetch-%D0%B8-Pull) все изменения с удаленного репозитория, но не мержит их.

> посмотреть какие файлы получены и что в них было изменено

Для этого делайте `git log master..origin/master`. Показывает лог между вашим мастером и удаленным.

> потом сделать слияние

Для этого делайте `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. Мержит ваш мастер с тем, что было стянуто.