# Локальная ветка и pull request

Tags: git, github

Начал осваивать Git и Github и возник такой вопрос. Когда из приложения Github desktop хочу создать pull request в ветку dev из локальной ветки, то меня просят опубликовать её. Обязательное ли это условие и если нет, то какие настройки репозитория нужно изменить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: pull request — это не команда git, а надстройка github. Соответственно ветка должна быть на github, то есть опубликована. Вместо этого вы можете выполнить локальный merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял Ваш вопрос - ответ: "Да, это обязательное условие".

Поясню.

Вот у Вас есть репозиторий.

Вы создаете ветку `dev`. Пока - эта ветка существует только локально.

Теперь Вы хотите сделать в неё PR. Это - такая штука, которая предлагает перенести изменения из одной ветки в другую.

Логично, что при этом обе ветки должны существовать - поэтому и нужно, чтобы dev была опубликована

Если кто то видит пробелы в моей логике - поправьте меня? и еще - можно посмотреть ответ вот на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505731/)