# Не могу запушить на git

Tags: git, github

Склонировал **свой** проект с github'a, на рабочую машину.
После проделанных действий в коде, решил запушить коммит на гит:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Something"
git push origin master
```

После попытки пуша, вылетела следующая ошибка:

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.3' to the list of known hosts.
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Я понял, что комиты я делаю только локально, но **как** мне **комитить в свой же удаленный репозиторий**(чтоб мог работать и тут и дома). 
Пробовал делать pull request в мастер, но видимо нужно создавать дополнительно ветку(это обязательно?)

P.S. Также просмотрел возможность работы [Fork](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505731/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-pull-request-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-push) , но опять же, если правильно понял, то это для работы с "чужим"(интересующим) меня репозиторием.

Comment: И ещё: [Как сделать commit в свой репозиторий после клонирования чужого?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/464140/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-commit-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%87%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be)

Comment: во всех ответах не сказано главного - нужно добавить свой ключик в гитхаб.

Comment: @KoVadim я залогинился просто в AndroidStudio, но этого не достаточно. Ключ, вы имеете в виду SSH? но обязательно ли это, если я клонирую https?

Comment: клонированеи и пуш - это две разные операции. И клонировать можно по http, а заливать (пушить) по ssh.

ключик лучше добавить. вначале проверьте, что он есть - https://help.github.com/articles/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys/ потом, если нет - сгенерируйте - https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/ и в конце добавьте в свой аккаунт - https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Comment: Key is invalid. It must begin with 'ssh-ed25519', 'ssh-rsa', 'ssh-dss', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp384', or 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp521'. Check that you're copying the public half of the key
видимо не то скопировал да?)

Comment: да, скорее всего. В гитхаб нужно выкладывать публичный ключ (он обычно называется id_rsa.pub, его можно всем показывать). А вот приватный нужно держать при себе и никому не показывать  (он обычно называется id_rsa).

Comment: @KoVadim добавил.Но в студии ситуация не поменялась.

Comment: Есть простой способ проверить, что все сделано правильно - в git bash консоли выполните команду `ssh -T git@github.com` (возможно, нужно будет ответить `y` на предложение добавить в список известных хостов). Если все ок - Вы увидите свой ник нейм на гитхабе.

Comment: @KoVadim у меня мак, но всё же получилось. И опять же не совсем)
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Comment: Команда универсальная. Будет работать даже на маке. Судя по сообщению, теперь гит будет работать.

Comment: @KoVadim к сожалению нет, та же проблема.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Клонируйте через консоль.

Comment: @KoVadim Так мне опять клонировать к себе этот проект?

Comment: я рекомендую делать все через консоль. В том числе клонирование и делать его через ssh, а не http. а также потом пулить.

Comment: @KoVadim вроде как все работает исправно, спасибо. Жаль не могу + поставить за КОРРЕКТНУЮ помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Судя из сообщения, у тебя нет права записи в основную ветку репозитория.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, каким образом можно решить задачу? Пожалуйста, приведите минимальный самодостаточный пример кода, решающего проблему.

Comment: Как эти права "объявить", учитывая что это мой репозиторий, созданный ранее на домашнем пк.